# Using Cargo how to make Glassfish create tables without modifying the original EAR

Tags: glassfish, cargo, maven-cargo

How do you make Cargo maven plugin create tables on an embedded database using the Glassfish container. *without* modifying the original EAR?

If it was using asadmin, the `--createtables=true` can be added to create the tables on deployment.

At the moment I am creating the database as follows:

```
<cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
cargo.datasource.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver|
cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true|
cargo.datasource.jndi=jdbc/__default|
cargo.datasource.username=APP|
cargo.datasource.password=nonemptypassword
</cargo.datasource.datasource.derby>
```

The database is created successfully, but there are no tables (as expected) in it yet.  I need to tell the persistence provider to create the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the [doDeploy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.cargo/cargo-core-container-glassfish/1.4.2/org/codehaus/cargo/container/glassfish/GlassFish3xInstalledLocalDeployer.java#56) it does not appear to allow passing additional parameters.

I have actually fixed it on the CARGO source code.  https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-1245

So when the fix gets released, the following can be done to create the tables and drop them.

```
<cargo.glassfish.deploy.arg.1>--createtables=true</cargo.glassfish.deploy.arg.1>
<cargo.glassfish.undeploy.arg.1>--droptables=true</cargo.glassfish.undeploy.arg.1>
```